# Django when is concrete inheritance appropriate

Tags: python, django

Let me start by stating that I have looked at django-polymorphic for this and still have questions.  I have item models and many subtypes for items.  Currently, my models look like this.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    pass

class Television(Item):
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    screen_size = models.IntegerField()

class Fridge(Item):
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)
    stuff_about_fridge = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

I did this at first because then I wouldn't worry about all of the left joins when querying different item types that would be caused if my models looked like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

class Television(Item):
    screen_size = models.IntegerField()

class Fridge(Item):
    stuff_about_fridge = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

I am now reaching a point where I realize that I very often query all of the Item models together and have to left join information from the subtypes instead, so I am not really saving myself there.  My question is, even if I used something like django-polymorphic, would it make sense to A) put everything that is shared in the parent model and just specific things in the child models or to B) have it like I do where everything is in the child model, but they share a parent model PK just so that they can be queried together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models. This model will then not be used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class**"

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes

The point of using inheritance is for sharing common info as mentioned in option (A).

**Django-polymorphic makes using inherited models easier**, nothing more.

Reference: https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

That means, in conclusion, **option (A) is correct** even though if you use Django-polymorphic.

Below method is the right approach:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    upc = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand)

class Television(Item):
    screen_size = models.IntegerField()

class Fridge(Item):
    stuff_about_fridge = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```